# Recommended Permissions for SQL Account that will be creating new SQL Accounts

Tags: sql-server

Seeking some recommendations on how to handle a SQL account, that will be creating additional SQL accounts in the future...

**Scenario:**

Our Admin production app connects to SQL using an account called: **Admin_Main**, as stated in the connection string. When somebody creates a new user in the Admin app and assigns them a Reporting license, a new SQL Account is created on the instance, for the new user. The **Admin_Main** account is used to create this account.

I, of course, do not want to add more permissions to the **Admin_Main** account than needed, so my question is;

What are the permissions that I should add to this account, so that it's able to create new SQL Server accounts, but doesn't have Admin permissions on the instance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider encapsulating the T-SQL code in a proc and use [module signing](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#serverlevel) to provide the additional needed permissions. This will allow the `Admin_Main` account to perform the functions with no more the execute permissions on the proc.

Comment: Does this account then need to grant object level access to the new account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could assign the server role `securityadmin` to the **Admin_Main** account.

The `securityadmin` server role is documented as:

> Members of the securityadmin fixed server role manage logins and their properties. They can <kbd>GRANT</kbd>, <kbd>DENY</kbd>, and <kbd>REVOKE</kbd> server-level permissions. They can also <kbd>GRANT</kbd>, <kbd>DENY</kbd>, and <kbd>REVOKE</kbd> database-level permissions if they have access to a database. Additionally, they can reset passwords for SQL Server logins.
>
> **IMPORTANT:** The ability to grant access to the Database Engine and to configure user permissions allows the security admin to assign most server permissions. The **securityadmin** role should be treated as equivalent to the **sysadmin** role.

<sup>***Reference:*** [Server-Level Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017) (Microsoft | Docs)</sup>

Let's give that a try and see how far we can get...

## Creating SQL Server Login Admin_Main

We'll create a new SQL Server Login and assign that user the `securityadmin` server role:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [Admin_Main] WITH PASSWORD=N'MyShineyNewP@sswerd', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON
GO
ALTER SERVER ROLE [securityadmin] ADD MEMBER [Admin_Main]
GO
```

This is all done with an account that has the `sysadmin` server role and the result is:

```
Command(s) completed successfully.
```

## Login With Admin_Main

You can then open up a new database query window using the **Admin_Main** SQL Serer Login and the corresponding password. Once you have done that...

## Assigning Higher Privileges

...your new user is certainly going to try and increase his/her privileges by adding himself/herself to the `sysadmin` server role:

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD member [Admin_Main]
```

This results in the following:

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Cannot alter the server role 'sysadmin', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

So the SQL Server Login can't assign himself higher privileges.

## Creating a New User (Or: How Far Can I Get?)

Seeing as the **Admin_Main** is now allowed to create new SQL Server Logins, let's create a new user while still logged in as **Admin_Main** and add some server level roles. We'll do this in multiple steps to find out when assigning SQL Server roles will fail:

### Create Login

#### Input

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [New_User] WITH PASSWORD=N'MyShineyNewP@sswerd', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON
GO
```

#### Output

```
Command(s) completed successfully.
```

### Assign securityadmin Role

#### Input

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE [securityadmin] ADD MEMBER [New_User]
GO
```

#### Output

```
Command(s) completed successfully.
```

### Assign sysadmin SQL Server Role

#### Input

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [New_User]
GO
```

#### Output

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Cannot alter the server role 'sysadmin', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

## Conclusion

You will have to assign the SQL Server role `securityadmin` to the **Admin_Main** SQL Server Login to allow this account to create new SQL Server Logins and/or Windows Authenticated SQL Server Logins.

...and you can't assign permissions/privileges to other accounts that your initial accounts doesn't already possess.

Comment: Wow, awesome post and very informative, thank you. Works perfectly for what I'm doing.

Comment: Small addition: you might want to assign lower permissions than `securityadmin` for newly created SQL Server Logins. Something like `db_datareader` or maybe even just `SELECT` on certain tables. Just a thought.